# Cypress react cy.visit() any url that is not index

Tags: reactjs, testing, content-type, cypress

I just started using Cypress and I am trying to create a test for the Sign Up page.
When I do `cy.visit('/');` everything works fine but I want to go directly to the Sign Up page. When I try doing `cy.visit('/signup')` the tests fail. It returns code `200` but it has `content-type` = `null` so it fails.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could fix that doing:

```
cy.visit('/').then((win) => {
  win.location.href = '/signup'
});
```

Then, you have to include in your `cypress.json` file the following code to avoid cross origin errors:

```
{
   "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this kind of gets the job done but it breaks the fix I have for mocking the api calls that use fetch.